# How to remove "Content-Length mismatch: Request Header indicated 39 bytes, but client sent 0 bytes" this error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, xdomainrequest

I am trying to call azure web service(the service is in different domain) using XDomainRequest object. I have a common method in javascript that handles all my request that I am sending to this service.
The code works fine for all other browsers except IE. In IE browser it works fine for some requests and for some it throws following error in fiddler.
"Content-Length mismatch: Request Header indicated 39 bytes, but client sent 0 bytes".

I am using IE9 browser. Please tell me how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is the error message correct? Compare the size of the reponse content with the size given in the header. IF they are different correct the server-side script.

Comment: yes the error message is correct. I have not mentioned the content size in the script.It is working fine for other requests but the calls for which it is not working are made on document.ready function.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this, I think my question is related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831033/internet-explorer-causes-iis-500-error-when-attempting-to-access-reporting-servi

Comment: @Neil which version of IE you are using??

Comment: It affected all our users, so basically from 8 up to 10. I actually have a preview of 11 installed, but I tested on 9 and 10 too