# Internet Explorer causes IIS 500 error when attempting to access reporting services from a Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, reporting-services

I have a aspx web forms page that calls a SQL 2012 SSRS report hosted on a SQL 2012 reporting services server and uses the report viewer to display the report on the aspx page.

The issue is when I click the link to sent the parameters to the reporting server and run the report the page hangs (on IE only). On the IIS logs on the server there is a 500 error in the logs corresponding to the request. There is no matching error message in the Event Viewer on the server. When I view it on fiddler the request goes out but nothing comes back.

When I try to browse to the page on any browser other than Internet Explorer it displays correctly. Whats strange is that when I first deployed it and browsed to it using IE it worked correctly, but after about 5-10 minutes the issue would arise. If I do an IISRESET on the server it works correctly, but again after 5-10 minutes (or maybe after a certain amount of usage) the issue arises again.

I didn't change anything on the reports, the reporting server, or the page that calls the reports, so it's not a simple C# bug. The only thing that has changed in the config file is some entity framework connection strings.

If anyone has any idea of what to look for to help figure out what is causing this I would greatly appreciate it

EDIT:
The request does come back after about ten minutes or so, with the report. So for any browser other than IE the report comes back straight away and no 500 error occurs on the server. For IE, a 500 error appears in the IIS logs and after about 10 to 15 minutes of waiting the server returns the report

EDIT:
An example of what appears in the IIS Log for a failed IE Request:

`POST /Reporting/ - 443 nkennymgr 84.203.177.34 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 500 0 64 130390`

Comment: Does the [substatus code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891) give any clues?

Comment: I've added an example to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the following line from the Global.asax fixed the issue

```
 HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
```